# Ler arquivo .txt e gravar cada linha em uma variável - Python

Tags: python

Estou com dificuldades para gravar cada linha em uma variável para ser utilizada em um for. Em meu arquivo `.txt` possuo uma lista com vários contatos, exemplos:

```
55199xxxxxxx1@s.whatsapp.net
55199xxxxxxx2@s.whatsapp.net
```

O que estou precisando fazer é usar esse arquivo .txt para enviar mensagens de contato por contato.
Segue exemplo de como tentei fazer o código:

```
contatos = open("contatos.txt", "r")
linhas = contatos.readlines()
for linha in linhas:
    msg = "Boa tarde"
    mac.send_message_to(msg, linha)
contatos.close()
```

Esse metodo `mac.send_message_to()` está sendo importado de outro arquivo.

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você só quer salvar os contatos de forma que possam ser acessados depois, um a um. Se o arquivo for um contato por linha, basta inserir num vetor (list) e acessar depois.
Se o arquivo forem vários por linha, separados por algum caracter (vírgula, dois pontos, etc), você vai precisar processar a linha antes de inserir na lista.
Abaixo, um exemplo que deve funcionar.

```
contatos = open("contatos.txt", "r")
contatos_array = []
linhas = contatos.readlines()
for linha in linhas:
    contatos_array.append(linha)
contatos.close()

for contato in contatos_array:
    msg = "Boa tarde"
    mac.send_message_to(msg, contato)
```

Comment: Obrigado Lucas Amparo, era exatamente isso que eu buscava...
Porém estou com um erro na execução desse método -> mac.send_message_to.

É retornado: TypeError: () takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
Acho que este método não está aceitando o for que está sendo usado, ou não está entendendo o uso da variável contato...

Comment: Esse erro informado diz que a função "send_message_to" não tem nenhum argumento (0 positional arguments) e vc está tentando passar 2 (but 2 were given).
Veja a documentação do método para ver qual a forma correta de se enviar o dado.
Provavelmente, você deve ter q setar o conteúdo e o destinatário, do tipo setMsg() e setReceiver(), para depois enviar a mensagem com o send_mesage...

Comment: Segundo a própria documentação do autor -> 
https://github.com/danielcardeenas/whatsapp-framework/
`code`
mac.send_message_to("Hello", "5218114140740")
"""
def send_message_to(str_message, phone_number, disconnect_after=True):
    jid = Jid.normalize(phone_number)
    send_message(str_message, jid)
`code`

Essa é a forma de se enviar uma mensagem, e pelo que entendi estou seguindo o que é pedido, apenas tentando utilizar + de 1 contato por mensagem...